# BLOB object is not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Actually, I am trying to get image using an $http and I am storing that data in BLOB object so that I can use it after on

HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div  ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<button ng-click="download()">download</button>
    <img id="photo"/>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.download=function()
  {
     $http.get('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=image1&w=120&h=120').success(function(data){
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( data );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/png" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
    var img = document.querySelector( "#photo" );
    img.src = imageUrl;

        }).error(function(err, status){})
  }

}]);
```

Plunker for the same problem:http://plnkr.co/edit/4kFKsigCudIlWOAs2Vsz?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the responseType as "arraybuffer"

```
$http.get('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=15&txt=image1&w=120&h=120', {responseType: "arraybuffer"})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IKQKWkY6YMwodzpByx0f?p=preview